# QGIS 3: WFS and local shp

Tags: qgis, shapefile, wfs, getfeature

I am new with using WFS layers.

My issue is the following :
I have a local shapefile which contains a column with a unique id for each entity. I would like to download from a WFS only the vectors that have these same id.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can do a GetFeature storedquery `Get feature by identifier` to get a single feature by the identifier, so yes, you just need to loop the attribute table and do a request per row.

Comment: you can find required inputs for the request by describing the available stored queries like:  `http://YOUR/WFS/URL/ows?service=WFS&request=DescribeStoredQueries&version=2.0.0&`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to establish a **join** between the two sources (the local .shp and the distant wfs) using the common field (id).

To setup the join : right-click on a layer in the layer panel, select **properties** and then choose the **joins tab**.

Keep in mind that web services often limit the number of features returned.

So don't expect to do something "too powerful" ...

Comment: Thanks! If I understand correctly, in what you propose you must first download the WFS layer? Is it not possible to create this join before downloading, for example in the SQL query?

Comment: no no i think u should be able to setup the join without any download of the wfs layer. Test both cases ...

Comment: I just tried: unfortunately the join on the layers is only valid after downloading the WFS...
So I'm trying with the SQL query for the addition of the WFS. But I don't know how to take my shp layer into account in it. Any idea?
Thanks;)

Comment: you downloaded the wfs layer and you want to join your local file ? if yes why don't you join the layers as indicated (properties/joins tab) ?

Comment: sorry I shouldn't have been clear enough.
The idea would be to be able to download only the joinable entities. And not to download everything and then join what can be